# serviceWorker Scope, don't include some directories

Tags: scope, service-worker

Is it possible to include some directories in the  serviceWorker scope and not others?

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register(
    '/service-worker.js',{
        scope: '/',
        noscope: '/someDir/'
    }
).then(function(reg) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: No you can't do that. However why you wants to exclude some directories, Can you please explain your problem statement and your current code implmentation

Comment: I want SW to work on my entire site except one directory, a blog dir containing WordPress.  Specifically, I don't want it caching anything to do with the admin.

Comment: As I have mentioned you can't do that. if you dont add your relevant files in your cached list then you are good, As even if the scope is root if the resource is not found in cached then it will make a server call.

Comment: There is an alternate way also, in your fetch request you can exclude request which belongs to your subdirectory. you need to add a url check for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Vimal Patel's advice, I rewrote my fetch/clone code to prevent ServiceWorker from caching the admin templates used in my WordPress blog but not anything else including my WordPress pages themselves.

```
const fetchResponse = await fetch(event.request);
if(fetchResponse) {
    console.log('fetchResponse: ', event.request.url);
    if(!/blog\/wp\-/i.test(event.request.url)) {
        await cache.put(event.request, fetchResponse.clone());
    }
    return fetchResponse;
}
```

This solution works perfectly for me now.